# How to appropriately run an adonis or anosim test?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have microbiome data structured as follows:

| PatientID | Treatment | Response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | Pre. | Yes. |
| P1. | Post. | Yes. |
| P2. | Pre. | No. |
| P2. | Post. | No. |

where I want to look at differences in the microbiome between patients who did and didn't respond to drug treatment. I have approximately 40 patients.

I have used phyloseq to generate a bray curtis distance matrix:

```
bray_dist = phyloseq::distance(physeq, method="bray")
```

I now want to use that distance matrix to test for differences between patients who did and didn't respond. What is the correct way to do this with anosim or adonis?

I was thinking of this:

```
adonis(bray_dist ~ sample_data(physeq)$Response, distance = "bray", strata = sample_data(physeq)$Treatment)
```

But I am new to this and I am unsure if this is the correct way to do it: would the above test the pre and post samples individually?

Answer (score 0):

As i have understood, adonis test (permanova) only tells you if there is significance among your treatments, but unfortunately does not tell you between which of them are different, in order to do that, you need to use another package as "pairwiseAdonis".

pairwiseAdonis::pairwise.adonis(your_distance-matrix, factors = metadata$Treatment, perm = 999).

But, if the differences in variation among your treatments are very big, i recommend to try with ANOSIM; unfortunately i dont know about any package in R that could do pairwise test, in such case i use the PAST software.

https://past.en.lo4d.com/windows